# Request.addProperty("SayHello", "32"); doesnt pass 32?

Tags: android, asp.net, web-services, ksoap2

I am trying to pass a value from android to aspx web service. But the web service doesnt take the 32 that is passed in the below code.

```
Request.addProperty("SayHello", "32");
```

any help would be greatly appreciated.

my complete android code is as follows

```
package com.example.fp1_webservicedropdown;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

import org.ksoap2.*;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapObject;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapPrimitive;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.transport.*;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    TextView result;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        result = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);

        final String NAMESPACE = "http://sample.com/";
        final String METHOD_NAME = "SayHello";
        final String SOAP_ACTION = "http://sample.com/SayHello";
        final String URL = "http://myLoclalIP/HellowWorld/Service1.asmx";

        SoapObject Request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
        Request.addProperty("SayHello", "32");

        SoapSerializationEnvelope soapEnvelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
        soapEnvelope.dotNet = true;
        soapEnvelope.setOutputSoapObject(Request);

        AndroidHttpTransport aht = new AndroidHttpTransport(URL);

        try {
            aht.call(SOAP_ACTION, soapEnvelope);
            SoapPrimitive resultString = (SoapPrimitive) soapEnvelope.getResponse();
            result.setText("The web service returned " + resultString);
        }

        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

my web service code is as follows:

```
 [WebService(Namespace = "http://sample.com/")]
    public class Service1 : System.Web.Services.WebService
    {
        [WebMethod]
        public  String SayHello(int a)
        {
            int passingValue = 8 + a;
            String aTemp=passingValue.ToString();
            return aTemp;
        }


    }
```

Comment: What value is printed on the server side...I mean do you have any logcat or console printing the value.Kindly share that

Comment: @curious i have added the web method code above. As a result it only prints 8.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't any method as addProperty in the docs for Request class. Although you can construct the URI as a string and pass it through constructor or use the `setDestinationUri(uri)` method.

For example,

```
uri = "http://www.mydomain.com/index?SayHello=32"
my_request.setDestinationUri(uri)
```

for more control there is also a method to set the HTTP headers yourself.

Comment: You're using SOAP, okay. The webservice method looks like it could be wrong?

Comment: oh, what changes do i need to make on the web service method so that i can add the passed value with 8?

Comment: You are returning a, you should return t

Comment: hey sorry that a error that i made when i put the code in here.. it is returning t..

Comment: It seems from your code that you are passing String from the client side  Request.addProperty("SayHello", "32"); whereas server is anticipating  an integer public int SayHello(int a).This might be a case.Have you checked upon this?

Comment: Then try logging the value of a? It could the it's not being taken as an integer?

Comment: when i go to the service and enter 32 it passes 40. Hey, ya i think that the problem. how can i pass a integer instead?

Comment: Cast it as an integer. I think this is how you do it int.Parse(a.Value);

Comment: @ape you mean you want me to return a string from the web method is it?

Comment: @curious you mean you want me to return a string from the web method is it?

Comment: my new web method looks as published above and still doesnt seem to be working m8

Comment: No I mean the SayHello(int a) change it to SayHello(String a).Once you get the String then typecast it using Integer.parseInt(a).

Comment: @curious my current web method is like this:

 [WebMethod]
        public  String SayHello(String a)
        {
           
            int passingValue = int.Parse(a);
            int temp= (passingValue+8);
            return temp.ToString();
        }

Comment: have you printed the String inside the Webmethod.What I mean to say is what is the value of a in webmethod.Have you printed the value of a inside SayHello method?Also you cannot do temp.toString() as in java int cannot be converted directly to String by this way.Rather you need to use Integer wrapper object.Kindly validate the same

Answer (score 0):

This is the Example...

```
package com.mehul.Web_Service;

import org.ksoap2.SoapEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.PropertyInfo;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapObject;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE;

import android.R.string;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class Web_ServiceActivity extends Activity 
{
    //SoapObject request; 
    Button ok,btnimage;
    EditText eprice;
    TextView tprice;


    private final String NAMESPACE = "http://www.webserviceX.NET/";
    private final String URL = "http://www.webservicex.net/stockquote.asmx";
    private final String SOAP_ACTION = "http://www.webserviceX.NET/GetQuote";
    private final String METHOD_NAME = "GetQuote";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        ok = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnok);
        eprice = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edtprice);
        tprice = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtprice);
        Typeface typface=Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"fonts/Gretoon.ttf");
        tprice.setTypeface(typface);

        ok.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
        {

            public void onClick(View v) 
            {
                    SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
                    PropertyInfo weightProp =new PropertyInfo();
                    weightProp.setName("symbol");

                    weightProp.setValue(eprice.getText().toString());

                    weightProp.setType(string.class);
                    request.addProperty(weightProp);


                    SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
                    envelope.dotNet = true;
                    envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
                    HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);

                    try 
                    {
                        androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
                        //SoapPrimitive response = (SoapPrimitive)envelope.getResponse();
                        SoapObject obj1 = (SoapObject)envelope.bodyIn;
                        //Log.i("myApp", response.toString());


                        //tv.setText(weight+" "+fromUnit+" equal "+response.toString()+ " "+toUnit);

                        String str = obj1.toString();
                        Log.d("My Price", ""+str);
                        int start = str.indexOf("<Last>")+("<Last>").length();
                        int end = str.indexOf("</Last>");

                        tprice.setText(""+str.substring(start,end)+" Price");
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Set Price Successfully .. "+str.substring(start,end), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


                       request = null;

                    } 
                    catch (Exception e) 
                    {
                        //e.printStackTrace();
                        Log.d("Exception Generated", ""+e.getMessage());
                    }

            }
        });

        //String weight = "ITC";
        //String fromUnit = "Grams";
        //String toUnit = "Kilograms";



        /*PropertyInfo fromProp =new PropertyInfo();
        fromProp.setName("FromUnit");
        fromProp.setValue(fromUnit);
        fromProp.setType(String.class);
        request.addProperty(fromProp);

        PropertyInfo toProp =new PropertyInfo();
        toProp.setName("ToUnit");
        toProp.setValue(toUnit);
        toProp.setType(String.class);
        request.addProperty(toProp);
        */ 



    }


}
```

Comment: you are passing string and in method takes as integer ?

Comment: can you show me the web method to add the passed number with 8

Comment: my current web method looks like this:
[WebMethod] public String SayHello(String a) { int passingValue = int.Parse(a); int temp= (passingValue+8); return temp.ToString(); }

Comment: Check the log ..in this function by Putting ...Log.d("log","Value"+passingValue);

Comment: no since the web method is in asp.net i cant use Log.. sorry im a beginner.

Comment: you have to pass only one value in your method why you are writing request.addProperty("Say Hello ",32);..you only need to pass 32 that i think...

Comment: can you please fix it for me. I just got stuck doing the changes

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/20872/discussion-between-mehul1000-and-najjaseven)